# Storypencil flicker

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor, keyframes, grease-pencil, scene

When using Storypencil and I go into the VSE, I get a flicker/stagger/lag during playback.
Could I be doing something to make that happen? What could the remedy be?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So I'm in Storypencil and draw a few frames, say of a bouncing ball. When I play the keyframes in the Grease Pencil viewport, everything plays back fine. However, when I swtich back to the Video Sequencer Editor and hit playback there, instead of a smooth playback, what I get is a laggy, stuttering, flashing on and off of the frames. Instead of smoothly moving forward, it quickly jumps back and forth between the keyframes. Even when there's only 3 or four keyframes. Hopefully this clairifies the issue but let me know if there's anything else you need to know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen also, it has something to do with two scenes linked to the same strip playing over themselves.

I had some luck fixing this by going to the *Browse Scene* tab (upper right) and delete the scene I think is causing it. Its more likely a bug then something we are doing wrong. No idea what cause it in my case.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response! It is greatly appreciated. Yeah, that makes sense. I'll try your suggestion next time. My only question then is, unless I'm misunderstanding, deleting the scene in the Browse Scene tab means you'd have to recreate it, yes? Thanks agian!